# USB-Serial FT232R not detected by Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, usb, samsung-mobile, usbserial, accessory

I am trying to connect a usb-serial accessory to my Samsung Galaxy S4 phone. The usb device is not detected in Android OS and not in the underlying LinuxSE (according to the app "USB Device Info" listing usb devices). The USB-Serial accessory uses the **ftdi chip FT232R**.

**Details:**
Model: Samsung Galaxy S4
Version: GT-I9505
Kernel: 3.4.0-526204

USB-Serial
Model FT232R
VendorId 0x0403
ProductId 0x6001

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the problem. The Samsung Galaxy S4 correctly identifies the USB-Serial accessory. Using a USB OTG cable resolves the issue. An USB OTG cable is needed as the Samsung Galaxy S4 in this case should be host (e.g. supplying the power).

Comment: Which cable do you have - for me all the Micro USB -USB adapters look the same